# Why is after_or_equal:now not working right at Date Validator in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Firstly, I had tried as follows;

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'starting_date' => 'date_format:"d-m-Y H:i:s" | after_or_equal:now ',
]);
```

The code doesn't work right. **after_or_equal:now**

Secondly, I had tried as follows;

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'starting_date' => 'after_or_equal:now | date_format:"d-m-Y H:i:s"',
]);
```

This worked right. Why didn't the first code work ? Could you explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can validate date :

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'starting_date'  =>  'required|date',
        'end_date'    =>  'required|date|after_or_equal:starting_date',
]);
```